# ${HOME}/Desktop directory somehow got moved in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, directory-structure, desktop-environment, home

I started up my laptop PC today and the `Desktop` directory inside my home folder has somehow been moved into a place other than `${HOME}/Desktop` and another `Desktop` directory exists inside my home directory but placing files inside of it does not make them show up on the actual graphical desktop while placing them inside `${HOME}/Desktop` actually does; How did this happen, and how do I fix it? — I tried naively using `rm -r ~/Desktop && mv ~/Downloads/Desktop ../`, but that didn't work. Below is the structure of the home directory:

```
${HOME}
├── Audiobooks
├── Desktop (this one is not the "actual" desktop)
├── Documents
├── Downloads
│   └── Desktop (this one is the actual desktop)
├── Music
└──  (and so on)
```

- **Distribution:** Linux Mint 18.1 Serena Cinnamon 64-bit
- **Kernel:** 4.4.0-83-generic
- **gnome-session-bin:** amd64/xenial-updates 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
- **libgnome-2-0:** amd64/xenial 2.32.1-5ubuntu1

Interestingly enough `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` looks strange as well:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Downloads/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

What happened here? — I didn't do anything with any configurations/settings myself.

Comment: Anything in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`?

Comment: Yes, in fact it says `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Downloads/Desktop"`... But how on Earth did this happen?